# Did Hodor know all along?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of *Game of Thrones* Season 6 Episode 5, *The Door*, we see

> How Hodor came to only say "Hodor"... he was *holding the door* while Bran was escaping and warged.

Does this mean

> Hodor saw his own death, and then knew for the rest of his life?

Comment: They really did that? Hodor and "Hold the door" is an [internet meme](http://winryrockbells.tumblr.com/post/45875388824/i-have-a-theory-on-aegon-theres-a-boy-claimed) :D

Comment: Do we really have to substitute "this character" for "Hodor", considering the fact that the title doesn't reveal what Hodor knew?

Comment: I think this question is opinion based. Moreover, it feels it is unrelated to the rest of the show/books. Hodor might just get shocked because of being warged. What he see and what he did not see is just conjecture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Probably not.

This is obviously based on a personal deduction (this question is fairly opinion-based), but in my opinion it is pretty close to what happened.

So, we have Bran warging into present Hodor **while he is still in the past**. This is pretty much fact: we see Hodor's eyes go white for an instant (as they did the first time Bran warged into him) , and then he acts in a resolved way he only showed when possessed by Bran. Moreover, he does not say "Hodor" once (which suggests again he is not himself at that moment).

From how the scene is assembled, we can assume that, in order to be able to warging into present Hodor, Bran uses the past one as some sort of bridge. This is backed up by three facts:
a) Past Hodor looks directly at Bran
b) Past Hodor does not fall unconscious or lose will during the whole scene, he just seems lightheaded and confused
c) Well, the whole outcome.

So the past Hodor is probably not really seeing what's happening in the future. He is just getting vague feelings of what is going on at both sides, including the feelings he gets from present Hodor's death and Meera's voice.

To sum it up, past Hodor saw Bran and he experienced vague feelings of what was going on in the future, including a death experience that leaves him permanently scarred. The common objection to this "why wasn't he scared by Bran then" can be explained by the fact that he saw him grow up.

Ps: I agree that the initial Hodor panic may be related to him getting strange deja-vu from the whole setting, but not to him consciously remembering everything that happened.

Comment: +1 because you suggested the question is opinion-based. It can be anything.

Comment: Your point (b) is wrong. Past Hodor has a seizure - he's not lightheaded and confused, he's flopping around on the ground screaming "hold the door" over and over again. That's why I actually thought Bran warged into past Hodor and somehow the seizure that past Hodor experienced was the trauma from Bran basically "programming" him for that moment many years in the future. I'm not sure if it's clear at this point exactly what happened there.

Comment: I meant he is lightheaded and confused before the seizure happens. In that "moment" past-Bran has already warged into future Hodor via him

Answer (score 6):

### Yes

At least, that would seem to be the implication.

He saw

> his future self holding back hordes of White Walkers, when Bran vision-quested to the past.

The trauma

> of witnessing his future self die seems to have deeply affected Hodor, causing him to be incapable of saying anything but the phrase he heard in the vision.

He could hardly have failed to make the connection;

> his future appearance (in particular his size) was probably similar enough to his present one for him to make the connection.

In any case, he may have also

> connected to the mind of his older self, which would guarantee that Hodor (then Wylis), would know exactly how he was going to die.

[This article](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/05/game-of-thrones-recap-605-hodor-the-door) concurs, suggesting that:

> No wonder the poor guy was shaking with fear as the Night’s King and his army of wights stormed the tree stump. He knew how this episode would end long before the rest of us did.

In any case, even if had failed to make the connection immediately, once he

> began to look more like the man in his vision

he probably would have realized.

Comment: How would Hodor/Wylis see into the future, Was he a Greenseer?

Comment: "No wonder the poor guy was shaking with fear as the Night’s King and his army of wights stormed the tree stump." Really? Meera was shaking with fear as well. Moreover, when did we see Hodor thinking and acting concretely?  Him being over stressed does not have to be related to Bran warging into him in the past. This answer is, as well as the question opinion-based.

Comment: @j4rey89 My take is that Bran was showing him/programming him.

Comment: I don't think he ever saw his future self...

Comment: It looked to me like he was *experiencing* the future events, not watching them from a 3rd-person perspective. That would seem to be necessary to explain him shouting "hold the door".